# Excel VBA - copy/paste rows

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to read in a range consisting of a single row on cells `A1:G1` into an array with 10 rows and then output the results on the same sheet in cells `A2:G11`. The data in the input row changes as it is based on formulas containing random numbers.  I'm told that the fastest way to do this is with an array. Not sure how to do that. So far I have the code shown below. This doesn't work because it won't recalculate the input data before it pastes it into the output cells so it keeps pasting the same values over and over. What is the best way to tackle this?

```
Sub MyRange()
Dim DataInput As Variant
Dim NumberOfSims As Long, i As Long

Application.Calculation = xlManual
NumberOfSims = 10

DataInput = Range("DataInput").Value

For i = 1 To NumberOfSims
    Range(Cells(1 + i, "A"), Cells(1 + i, "g")).Value = DataInput
    Application.Calculate
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`DataInput` never changes because `DataInput = Range("DataInput").Value` is *outside* the loop, so the same values will get pasted over and over.

Move it inside and it will update with each iteration.

```
Sub MyRange()
    Dim DataInput As Variant
    Dim NumberOfSims As Long, i As Long

    Application.Calculation = xlManual
    NumberOfSims = 10

    For i = 1 To NumberOfSims
        DataInput = Range("DataInput").Value
        Range(Cells(1 + i, "A"), Cells(1 + i, "G")).Value = DataInput
        Application.Calculate
    Next i

End Sub
```

You can avoid using an array altogether and just transfer the value:

```
For i = 1 To NumberOfSims
    Range(Cells(1 + i, "A"), Cells(1 + i, "G")).Value = Range("DataInput").Value
    Application.Calculate
Next i
```

---

**EDIT:**

Instead of continually re-calcing and rereading from the sheet, you could read the formulas into an array, `Evaluate` them and then write back to the the sheet all at once.

Perhaps something like this:

```
Sub MyRange()
    Dim NumberOfSims As Long, NumberOfCols As Long

    NumberOfSims = 5000
    NumberOfCols = Range("DataInput").Columns.Count

    Dim InputFormulas() As Variant
    InputFormulas = Range("DataInput").Formula

    Dim OutputValues() As Variant
    ReDim OutputValues(1 To NumberOfSims, 1 To NumberOfCols)

    Dim R As Long, C As Long

    For R = 1 To UBound(OutputValues, 1)
        For C = 1 To UBound(OutputValues, 2)
            OutputValues(R, C) = Application.Evaluate(InputFormulas(1, C))
        Next C
    Next R

    Range("A2").Resize(UBound(OutputValues, 1), UBound(OutputValues, 2)).Value = OutputValues
End Sub
```

Comment: 'Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic' at the end?

Comment: That works! Thanks. If the number of iterations is big (say over 5,000), this takes a while to run.  Is there a way using arrays which will speed it up?

Comment: It's just RAND(). In reality it will pull from a formula on another page which uses a random number generator. But this will do as a test.

Comment: See the edit. It's a lot faster, because it only reads from the sheet once and writes to the sheet once.